# html frame equivalent in flutter

Tags: flutter-layout, frame

is there an equivalent of html frame in flutter ,
like let us supposes we have a list of links on right side as a column and if i press links respective page has to open in another frame, how to achieve this in flutter ?

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

- 1.html     +                                +
- ```
           +                                +
  ```
- 2.html     +                                +
- ```
           +                                +
  ```
- 3.html     +                                +
- ```
           +                                +
  ```
- ```
           +                                +
  ```
- ```
           +                                +
  ```
- ```
           +                                +
  ```
- ```
           +                                +
  ```
- ```
           +                                +
  ```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++